# Entity validation in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I have a question regarding the entity validation in the Thymeleaf framework.

When I delete/change an attribute in my entity and this attribute is used in the template, is there a way to validate the attribute when the project is compiled?

So currently, the project compiles correctly and it fails when the page using this attribute is loaded.

Is there a way to configure the project when its compiled? This helps as a lot when we are refactoring some entities.

Thanks in advance,
Talat

Comment: Is the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40850926/nameof-equivalent-in-java#46679366 an option for you?

Comment: I'm not sure if this would help.

Comment: Render the template in a unit test?

Comment: That's actually a good solution. Do have an example on hand? Thanks for the idea. However, if there is a configuration I can do to prevent the compilation, this would be awesome.