# How to get field name in android

Tags: java, android, logging, field-names

I'm creating camera app and I want to log infos about camera state. Now I'm using:

```
Log.i("AF state", String.valueOf(result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE)));
```

It returns values like:

```
I/AF state: 1
```

It is hard to read and I'm curious if there is a way to log field names that these numbers represent, for example:

```
I/AF state: CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_FOCUSED_LOCKED
```

Comment: would you please add more code explaining the context? what does the `result.get` method do? can you share the definition of the `CaptureResult` enum?

Comment: this question is already asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14944333/get-name-of-a-field

Comment: result is CaptureResult type from CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getName()`

```java
Log.i("AF state", result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE).getName());
```

from [*Android Developer Docs*](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureResult.Key)

```
Return a camelCase, period separated name formatted like:

"root.section[.subsections].name".
```

Comment: Unfortunately this method doesn't exist here.